# How to bage Number in iOS app while app is closed

Tags: ios, push-notification, badge

I am using badge notifications in my app and it works fine but I get the badge number by calling a method. So if method is called then the badge number gets increased but how to call that method while app is closed.

```
  - (void)repeatedMethod {

    SOWObject *object =[[SOWObject alloc]init];
    [object getBadgeNumber:[self getDBPath]];

    // I get badgeArray from above method

     [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber=badgeArray.count;

    }
```

is there any way we can call this method each day when date is changed and update badge number.

Comment: You're looking for Local notifications.

Comment: yes but how to set bage number as I am using method to get the array count

Answer (score 2):

So far as I know, you can do this with 3 options:

1. Use Silent notification - for iOS7 and above only. a bit complicated since you need to enable Push and do back-end intergration
2. Use Background refresh - Create a timer + `UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier`. (not 100% sure)
3. Use Local/Push Notification - disadvantage using this, user knows of such notification is triggered.

Answer (score 0):

implement this delegate method in your appdelegate:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notif
```

This method is fired whenever the OS finds any local notifications.(it doesn't matter whether your app is in the background or in the foreground).

For more information & code  look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16811466/local-notification-in-background)

Look at the accepted answer.

Edited:
Answer for you to call a method while app is in background is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8167956/how-can-i-call-method-while-app-is-in-background-in-ios)

So, it basically says not all the apps have access to background execution. Officially it's mentioned in the apple's developer site also: [HERE](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW20)

Comment: but where to call the method where we set Notification so it should repeat every 30 seconds