# How to run webServices when App even at BackGround state in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Hi I am new for Ios and in my app I want to run my Web services with **BackGround Thread** and I want to run this web Service even when app at Background State.

How can I do this Scenario? Can some one help me please?

My code is below.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    [self getServieCalling:@"MY URL"];
}

-(void)getServieCalling :(NSString*)mainurl{


    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{


    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:mainurl,kServerBaseURL1]]

                                                           cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy

                                                       timeoutInterval:60.0];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    NSURLSessionTask *task = [[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

        if (error != nil) {

            NSString * BasicnetworkError = [error localizedDescription];
            NSString * AppendString = @"Http Response failed with the following ";
            NSString * networkError = [AppendString stringByAppendingString:BasicnetworkError];

            [self BasicError:networkError];

            return;
        }

        else if ([response isKindOfClass:[NSHTTPURLResponse class]]) {

            NSInteger statusCode = [(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response statusCode];
            if (statusCode != 200) {

                NSString *statusCodeError = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Http Response failed with the following code %ld", (long)statusCode];



            }else{

                NSError *parseError;

                id responseObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&parseError];

                NSLog(@"response object %@",responseObject);


                else {

                    NSLog(@"Error parsing JSON: %@", parseError);

                    NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

                    NSLog(@"responseString = %@", responseString);
                }
            }
        }

    }];

    [task resume];

   });
}
```

Comment: Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15268702/implementing-long-running-tasks-in-background-ios

Comment: i my code i wrote clearly how to run web services in using background thread but my question how to run this operation when app even at background state?

Comment: That answer deals with background mode dude. Have you read it properly. It about running your code in background state .

Comment: NSOperationQueue* operationQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
[operationQueue addOperationWithBlock:^{
    // Perform long-running tasks without blocking main thread
}];

Comment: This will also help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8167956/how-can-i-call-method-while-app-is-in-background-in-ios

Comment: they provide above block for running app using Background thread

Comment: is this block perform even app at background state Vishal?

Comment: Have't you noticed this part of answer???? - (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    bgTask = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{

      // Wait until the pending operations finish
      [operationQueue waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished];

      [application endBackgroundTask: bgTask];
      bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    }]; 
}

Comment: so what is this bgTask? i am not understand

Comment: bgTask = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
}];

Comment: can you explain me this clearly

Comment: i think [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15269029/1219956) explains it a bit better